# Glob imports of local enums in functions

Tags: rust

The recent enum namespacing changes in Rust have broken some of my old code. In order to try and get it to compile again, I have tried adding glob imports. Unfortunately I can't get this to work for enums defined within a function. I can't find a way to import the variants of a local enum into the local namespace.

```
#![feature(globs)]
fn main() {
    use self::Foo::*; // Does not work
    enum Foo {
        Bar,
        Baz
    }
    let x = Bar; // Error - Bar not found
}
```

What is the appropriate import statement to use in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't believe this to be possible.

`use` statements are *absolute* by default.  As such, `use Foo::*;` won't work because `Foo` is not in the root module.  `use self::Foo::*;` doesn't work because `self` refers to the containing module, *not* the containing scope (which in this case is a function within the containing module).

You can *kind of* work around this by placing the function and the enum in a module of their own, then re-export the function to the containing module.

```
use self::a::blah;
pub mod a {
    use self::Foo::*;
    enum Foo { Bar, Baz }
    fn blah() { /* use Bar and Baz... */ }
}
```